# Compiling C program with openwrt

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct{
   char startDate[12],endDate[12];
   short activeFlag: 8;
   short ruleNo;
   int duration;
   time_t end_time;
}usagesOnRule;

typedef struct 
{
    usagesOnRule timeBaseUsages[TIME_BASED_USG_NUM];
    time_t lstChrgngAtmptd;
    time_t lastUpdateTime;
    time_t lastBlockTime;
    long long macKey;
    uint32_t ipKey;
    uint32_t dropPkt;
    uint32_t sessionCnt[QTHREAD_SIZE];
    int16_t ruleList[USER_RULE_NO], ruleListCounter;
    int sessnStart, sessionNFq, resultCode;
    short failCount;
    short blocked;
    short timeBaseCounter;

    char macAddress[MAC_LEN];
    char ipAddress[IP_LEN];
 }user;

 user CurrentUser[USER_NUMBER];
```

this is my struct definition. my code with this structure is working with in compiler but when i tried to compile for another model, its showing

> error: 'struct user' has no member named 'ipAddress'
>    error: 'struct user' has no member named 'macAddress'

..............for all member.
anyone have idea?
I am posting part of my code. its huge not possible to post all codes

```
for (usrIndx = 0; usrIndx < USER_NUMBER; ++usrIndx)
{
    if (CurrentUser[usrIndx].ipKey == 0)
        continue;
    if (strcmp(CurrentUser[usrIndx].macAddress, msg2) == 0)
        {
        sessnIndx = CurrentUser[usrIndx].sessnStart;
        qIndx = CurrentUser[usrIndx].sessionNFq;
        sessionCount = 0;
        if (CurrentUser[usrIndx].sessnStart > 0)
        {
        while (sessnIndx > 0)
        {
            sessionCount++;
            sprintf(reply, "%s%s|%d|%s|%s\n", reply, CurrentSession[qIndx][sessnIndx].destIp, CurrentSession[qIndx][sessnIndx].destPort, CurrentSession[qIndx][sessnIndx].hostName, CurrentSession[qIndx][sessnIndx].appProtocol);
            sessnIndx = CurrentSession[qIndx][sessnIndx].next;
                        }
                    }
        sprintf(reply, "%sTotal_Session_of_%s_%d\n", reply, CurrentUser[usrIndx].macAddress, sessionCount);
                }
            }
```

Comment: You haven't defined `struct user` in the code shown... only `user` (as a typedef of an unnamed struct).  Are you using `struct user` instead of just `user` in other parts of your code? (In C, the two are not interchangeable).

Comment: You need to show us the code that the compiler is complaining about, not the code for which it does work.

Comment: Keep removing all code that is not necessary to produce the error until you have left the smallest possible code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reason behind to not compiling with user structure. For Some hardware architecture there is another structure named "User" in kernel module.

Just i renamed my structure name and its working fine.

cheers!